# Request to change the sample question and answers on the Tour page to something more relevant to this site

Tags: support, status-completed, tour

On the current [tour page](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site, the example question and answer are completely irrelevant to the this site.

The sample question is:

> How to prevent unicorns from eating daisies
>
> I love the unicorns who hang out behind my kitchen, but they do tend
>   to eat rather a lot of the daisies. What can I do about this?

The sample (accepted) answer is:

> The easiest solution is to spray the daisies lightly with corn syrup
>   using a standard vegetable oil sprayer. It won't hurt the flowers, but
>   unicorns hate the sickly-sweet smell and will avoid it at all costs!

I request the dev team to have a look into this issue and change the sample question/answer to something more relevant. Maybe add one one of the most upvoted questions on this site, as sample, like this one: [Can a Turing machine simulate a quantum computer?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1/can-a-turing-machine-simulate-a-quantum-computer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system will select questions (or Moderators can do so) once the site has sufficient activity for that feature to work. I don't recall the exact criteria, but when I try to pick questions to replace those placeholders, the system reports

> There are currently no viable question candidates for the About page

In essence, there is not yet enough activity on this site to supplant the placeholders on the tour page. Keep working on your content. I don't think we are that far off.

Comment: Ok, the 'quantum similating question has my vote, since' 1. It is a decent question and 2) there is a short, but not bad answer and there is a clearly better and longer answer (hence the 'best answers rise to the top is clear')

Comment: @RobertCartaino It has been a few days. Perhaps you could check again if there are questions that can replace the unicorns?

Comment: @RobertCartaino in addition to what Discrete lizard said: We already have more questions than other public-beta sites and they have some non-unicorn questions already.

Comment: Choosing a question for the Tour page says: `There are currently no viable question candidates for the About page`.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163947/what-determines-the-questions-available-for-selection-in-the-tour-page

Comment: @RobertCartaino is there an update regarding a change of the the question on the tour page?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this seems to be a good idea but I would propose a different example question because most other sites show short questions with short answers on their tour page.

Short, high scoring questions with short accepted answer are for example:

- [Can a quantum computer simulate a normal computer?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23/can-a-quantum-computer-simulate-a-normal-computer) (probably not so good as it has only one answer)
- [How does bra-ket notation work?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-does-bra-ket-notation-work) (has two short answers, maybe question a bit too long (with the edit))

*(Just looked at the first page of questions sorted by votes)*

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, we should do this ASAP! So experts might not like unicorns and as we aren't actually discussing unicorns, we might chase away experts that happen to hate unicorns!

Answer (score 0):

And the question has been automatically selected as [What are reliable references on analytical and/or numerical studies of threshold theorems under faulty quantum error correction?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/3828/23)

It's possible (but certainly not necessary) that we could manually change that in the future if people so wished, once (if) other suitable questions get asked and answered. [Apparently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163948/349720), the question as well as two answers to that question need to be less than or equal to 400 character to be suitable and there's a [SE Data Explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/quantumcomputingme/query/92078/possible-about-questions) for this.

Thanks to @Sherif F. for writing the question and @DaftWullie and @Dripto Debroy for writing the answers!